# Is this a standard proof for convergence of the stochastic gradient descent scheme?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization

Take the rather simple and restrictive setting where we have an objective function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is doubly differentiable, strongly convex and has Lypschitz continuous gradient, i.e, $f$ is such that
$$  \ell I \le \nabla^2 f(x) \le L I  $$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $0< \ell < L \in \mathbb{R}$ . Call its unique minimum point $x^*$.

Suppose we were only given a sequence of independent random variables $\{  X_1 , X_2, \dots, X_n  \}$ s.t. $E_{X_1}[ X_1 ] =\nabla f( x_1), E_{X_2}[ X_2 ] =\nabla f( x_2)$ and so fourth and we were to apply stochastic gradient descent from an arbitrary point $x_0$ to the objective function $f$, that is recursively computing

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha X_k $$

and we want to prove convergence of this scheme, could we just proceed as follows:

Notice that from the mean value theorem we have
$$\nabla f(x_k) = \nabla f(x_k) - \nabla f( x^*) = \nabla^2 f(c) ( x_k - x^*  ) $$
where $c$ is a point in between $x_k $ and $x^*$. So taking expectations wrt the joint probability of $X_1, X_2, ... X_n $ we obtain
$$ E[\nabla f(x_k)]  = E[\nabla^2 f(c)] ( E[x_k] - x^*  )   $$

where $\ell I \le E[\nabla^2 f(c)] \le LI$ at this point notice that

$$ || E[x_{k+1}] - x^*    ||  =  || E[x_{k}] - \alpha E[ X_k ] - x^*    || = || E[x_{k}] - \alpha E[\nabla f(x_k) ] - x^*    || \le || I - \alpha E[\nabla^2 f(c)] ||  ||  E[x_{k}] - x^*   ||  $$
and utilizing the fact that $|| I - \alpha E[\nabla^2 f(c)] ||= \max\{ |1- \lambda_1  |,  |1- \lambda_n  |  \} \le \max\{ |1- \alpha \ell |,  |1- \alpha L |  \} $ we can choose the stepsize $0 <\alpha < L /2$ to conclude that
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} ||  E[x_{k+1}] - x^*  || = 0$$

Would this be a standard proof for the convergence of stochastic gradient descent? I recall it being longer.

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious, but why are you able to split the expectation as $E[\nabla^2 f(c) x_k] = E[\nabla^2 f(c)]E[x_k]$?

Comment: @brenderson That is a very good question, I don't think I can. Thanks! Maybe you could even help me try to salvage the proof

Comment: @brenderson I believe the proof still holds proceeding by cases, first taking the case $E[ \nabla^2 f(c) (x_k - x^*  ) ] \le L E[  (x_k - x^*  ) ]$  and then the case $E[ \nabla^2 f(c) (x_k - x^*  ) ] \le \ell E[  (x_k - x^*  ) ]$, the $\alpha$ chosen should solve both cases, do you agree?

Comment: What about 
$$
\begin{align}
E[x_{k+1} - x_k] &= -\alpha E[ \mathbf{X}_k] \\
E[x_{k+1} - x_k] &= - \alpha \nabla f(x_k) \\
E[x_{k+1} - x_k] &= - \alpha \nabla^2(x_k - x^*) \\
E[x_{k+1} - x_k] &\leq -\alpha \ell (x_k - x^*) \\
E[x_{k+1} - x_k] / (x_k - x^*) &\leq -\alpha \ell
\end{align}
$$
and just let $k \rightarrow \infty$ for some small $\alpha < \frac{1}{\ell}$. Maybe I am missing something